# sum equal zero for variables for sas

Tags: sql, sas

I looked at the internet but I could not find anything relevant.

I have a table with thousands of variable.

I'm trying to do a sum of one single variable and find out , which variable in sum , is equal to zero.

example

```
col1 col2 col3
0    0    0
1    0    2
1    0    3
```

results

```
col2
0
```

However, my `proc means` does not want to take my where clause.

```
proc sql;
create table toto as select nomvar,monotonic() as num_lig from dicofr 
where nomvar <> 'date';


proc sql;
select nomvar into :varnom separated by ' ' from toto 
where num_lig between 0 and 1000;

%put varnom: &varnom;

proc means data=afr sum (where=(sum(&varnom)=0) ;
var &varnom;
output out=want;
run;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for anything that can lead me to a solution.

Comment: I don't know that I completely follow what you want.  Do you really just want `col2` (the variable name) as output to this whole thing?

Comment: Hi Joe, my table has many columns , some of them with only zero in the observations for a specific column.

Like my example, I want to know , which column/variable has nothing but only zeroes.

Is it clear? If not, please let me know.

Comment: How do you want to obtain this information?  Do you want a dataset that has `varname` as a variable and each row is a variable name of a variable with only zero sum?

Comment: If they are in dataset, that's ok. But one thing, I feel this is not something overly complex. Maybe I'm wrong but if not, I would need a solution that I can understand easily. As you know, I'm still very much of a beginner with SAS and the understanding will help me reproduce it and make the solution easier to grasp. I tried with my limited SAS knowledge but I guess something is missing here , although I may not be too far with what i'm trying to achieve. Sorry for this long comment.

Comment: I would suggest that the problem here is you're trying to operate on variables as if they were rows, not columns.  That's fine, but your data isn't that way.  You can either use a proc like I do in my example, or you can transpose your data to long format - ie, just `id variable_name value` variables, and lots of rows per id.  Then you have a lot of easy ways to get to where you want - in SQL, in procs, in data step, whatever.

Comment: Indeed Joe. I was asking around and some other folks said as well I should aim for a transpose.

Comment: Just as an aside, you are missing a close bracket in your code.  It should be (where=(sum(&varnom)=0))

Comment: Hi Keith, I've tried but it is a no go. Alas. it is giving me this 

56   proc means data=afr sum (where=(sum(&varnom)=0))  ;
                             -
                             22
                             76

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it.  I believe this requires SAS 9.3+ for the `stackedodsoutput` option.

```
*Generating some data;
data have;
array x[100];
call streaminit(7);
do i = 1 to 20;
 do _t = 1 to dim(x);
   if rand('Uniform') < 0.9 then x[_t]=0;
   else x[_t]=1;
 end;
 output;
end;
run;

*ods output grabs what you want from proc means;
ods output summary=want(where=(sum=0));
proc means data=have sum stackodsoutput;
var x:;
run;
ods output close;
```

Comment: Hi Joe,almost there. I've got the following ERROR: Variable var47304 in list does not match type prescribed for this list.
ERROR: Variable var110176 in list does not match type prescribed for this list.
ERROR: Variable var152194 in list does not match type prescribed for this list. The columns have missing values inside. Should the sum take the missing values as well??

Comment: Just found that some of my columns are alphanumeric. This is the reason of the errors. Cheers Joe.

Comment: `proc summary` and `proc means` are identical nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to achieve this, here's a datastep/array method :

```
%LET NVARS = 1000 ;

data want ;
  set have end=eof ;
  array n{*} col1-col&NVARS ;
  array t{&NVARS} 5. _TEMPORARY_ ;

  do i = 1 to dim(n) ;
    t{i} + n{i} ;
  end ;

  if eof then do ;
    do i = 1 to dim(t) ;
      if missing(t{i}) or t{i} = 0 then do ;
        vname = vname(n{i}) ;
        put "Sum of " vname "= 0" ; /* write message to log */
        output ; /* Write to dataset */
      end ;
    end ;
  end ;
  keep vname ; 
run ;
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. However, is there not something simpler?

Comment: You could use a `proc summary data=want nway` without a `class` statement, and then read in the output dataset again, but you'd still need an array to iterate over the columns to find the zero-sum variables.